# PriorityQueue Comparator type conflict with Arrays.sort()

Tags: java

My Comparator is currently typed to `JobSet`.  I'm unsure why it has `<capture` - I've never seen that before.  Can someone shed some light on what's going on here?

The comparator...

```
public class JobSetComparator implements Comparator<JobSet> {
    @Override
    public int compare(JobSet o1, JobSet o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getHighestPriority().getValue(), o2.getHighestPriority().getValue());
    }
}
```

The queue...

```
protected JobSetQueue queue = new JobSetQueue(0, new JobSetComparator());

public JobSetQueue getQueue() {
    return queue;
}

public JobSet[] getPrioritizedQueue() {
    return Arrays.sort(queue.toArray(), queue.comparator());
}
```

[image]

Comment: All `Arrays.sort` methods return `void`, so you can't `return` what it returns, because it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @EJP - Please post something as the answer so I can give you credit... I was confused with how to use the PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 8):

`queue.toArray()` returns a `Object[]`, which your provided `Comparator` can't handle.

You will need to use the alternate [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), that takes an array of the expected type:

```
JobSet[] queueArray = queue.toArray(new JobSet[]{});
Arrays.sort(queueArray, queue.comparator());
return queueArray;
```